Questions on using Source Control with AnchorPoint and GitHub, on Custom Unreal Engine Build
I compiled a custom Unreal Engine build from Source Code (via Epic's GitHub Account) and wanted to source control my custom engine build from the start but ran into some issues and wanted to get some clarification.
To give some background on the process I took:
Downloaded the engine from Source Code (via Epic's GitHub account)

Engine Version was 4.25.4
Compiled the engine successfully from Source Code
Also created a new Unreal Engine project inside of this same folder
Git and Git LFS are installed
Initially bought 2 "Git LFS Data" packs on GitHub

Moving onto setting up project / repository inside of AnchorPoint software....

Created a new project / Git Repository from within AnchorPoint software

enter image description here
Its detecting 181712 changed files

Majority of these files are from the custom engine build
Some of these files are from the Unreal Engine Project created within the same parent folder

enter image description here
Attempted to execute "Sync"
enter image description here
Ran into the following error:
enter image description here
Saw "rate limit exceeded" so I thought maybe it had to do with not enough bandwidth to be able to handle large files, so I threw money at the problem and bought two more data packs (for a total of 4)

Then went back into the software and hit Push again

Hit retry when prompted with "There are newer changes on the server"
enter image description here
This time it seemed to actually commit all 181713 files successfully
enter image description here
This brings me to my questions. Looking for clarification on a few things

Q: Did I correctly set up my '.gitignore' file?


When initially creating the project / repository via AnchorPoint, I used the template feature inside of AnchorPoint to generate the .gitignore file
Q: If I'm trying to source control a custom engine build, is it still fine to use this default template that this generates? Or do I need to edit the .gitignore file to remove or add logic? (see gitignore file contents below).

# Visual Studio 2015 user specific files
.vs/

# Compiled Object files
*.slo
*.lo
*.o
*.obj

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch
*.pch

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so
*.dylib
*.dll

# Fortran module files
*.mod

# Compiled Static libraries
*.lai
*.la
*.a
*.lib

# Executables
*.exe
*.out
*.app
*.ipa

# These project files can be generated by the engine

*.xcodeproj
*.xcworkspace
*.sln
*.suo
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.VC.db
*.VC.opendb

# Precompiled Assets
**/SourceArt/**/*.png
**/SourceArt/**/*.tga

# Builds
**/Build/*

# Whitelist PakBlacklist-<BuildConfiguration>.txt files
!**/Build/*/
**/Build/*/**
!**/Build/*/PakBlacklist*.txt

# Don't ignore icon files in Build
!**/Build/**/*.ico

# Configuration files generated by the Editor
**/Saved/*

# Compiled source files for the engine to use
**/Intermediate/*

# Cache files for the editor to use
**/DerivedDataCache/*


Q: Looking at the process I attempted originally (and ran into problems with), did I do something wrong that caused me to run into the error: GIT LFS error: fatal: credential-cache unavailable; no unix socket support Rate Limit Exceeded?


Whats this error code trying to communicate?
Did I fix it by just buying 2 more GitHub LFS data packs (for a total of 4) or was that irrelevant?
Is there something generally wrong with the process I followed?


Q: Are there any other steps I need to complete in order to properly Source Control a custom engine build?

